# SqLite c++, can create database but can't insert anthing to a table

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I'm trying to create a function that append data from a QLineEdit to a SqLite db, the problem is, i manage to create the database and the tables, but every time I'm trying to add the actual data the program its unable to write to the db, even when the actual db its in use, im using `prepare()` from QsqlQuery to create the statement and then use `bindValue()` to add the actual variable, i cant use QDebug it simply wont show anything that's why I'm using too many QmessageBox()

Any ideas are welcome!

```
#include "Pantalla_Principal.h"
#include "ui_Pantalla_Principal.h"
#include <QWidget> // usar el widget
#include <QLabel> // usar label
#include <QObject>

#include <QDebug> // hacer debug
#include <QSqlError> //hacer debug sql


//#include "libusb.h"  // libreria para leer USB
//#include "../mariadb++/account.hpp"  // crea las conecciones a la base de datos mariadb
//#include "../mariadb++/connection.hpp" // maneja las conecciones
#include <QSqlDatabase> // crea conecciones a base de datos
#include <QSqlTableModel> // tabla de una sola columna
#include <QSqlRelationalTableModel> // tablas de varias columnas
#include <QSqlQuery> // hace las busquedas y agrega data a los registros
#include <QMessageBox> // crea los mensajes de advertencia
 ....
 ....
 ....

void Pantalla_Principal::Nuevo_Registro_Boletas(){
    wpp.setupUi(this);

    //obtener info del formulario boletas
    QString nombre=wpp.Nombre_Prod_edit->text();  
    QString apellido1=wpp.Apellido1_Prod_edit->text();
    QString apellido2=wpp.Apellido2_Prod_edit->text();
    QString predio=wpp.Predio_Nombre_edit->text();
    QString ubicacion=wpp.Predio_Ubicacion_edit->text();
    QString chofer=wpp.Nombres_Chofer_edit->text();
    QString c_apellido1=wpp.Apellido1_Chofer_edit->text();
    QString c_apellido2=wpp.Apellido2_Chofer_edit->text();
    QString placas=wpp.Placas_Camion_edit->text();
    QString color=wpp.Camion_Color_edit->text();
    QString tipo=wpp.Camion_Tipo_edit->text();
    QString apellidos = apellido1+" "+apellido2;

  //  variables para MYSQL
  //  QString host_name="127.0.0.1";
    QString name_db="CICLO-OI-19-20.db"; //  Base de Datos del Ciclo
  //  QString user="root";
  //  QString pass="agroindustrias";  // poner el nombre de usuario y pass de acuerdo a la base de datos
  //  int port=3306;

    //accesa a la base de Datos MariaDB usando QSql
    if (!QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QSQLITE")){
        QMessageBox::critical( this, "Error de Base Datos", "\n\n El driver SQL no esta disponible");
    }

    QSqlDatabase mData=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); // pones el tipo de driver de la db, en este caso QMYSQL
       mData.setDatabaseName(name_db); 
    //   mData.setHostName(host_name); //pon  el nombre o direccion del host
    //   mData.setPort(port); // puerto al que llamar
    //   mData.setUserName(user);
    //   mData.setPassword(pass);  

    if (!mData.open()){
        QMessageBox::critical( this, "Error de Base Datos", "\n\nBase de Datos no encontrada");
    }

    // llena la base de datos usando QSqlQuery
    QSqlQuery valor;
    valor.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boletas "
               "(Folio_Num INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
               "Chofer_Nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Chofer_Apellidos VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
               "Placas VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
               "Camion_Color VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Camion_Tipo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
               "Peso_Bruto INTEGER NOT NULL, Peso_Tara INTEGER NOT NULL,"
               "Peso_Neto INTEGER NOT NULL, Humedad DOUBLE NOT NULL,"
               "Retenciones DOUBLE NOT NULL, Impuresas DOUBLE NOT NULL )");
    if(!valor.exec()){
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","\n\n No se pudo crear las tablas");
    }else
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Logro","\n\n Tabla Creada");

    valor.prepare( "INSERT INTO boletas (Folio_Num, Chofer_Nombre, Chofer_Apellidos, Placas, Camion_Color,"
                   "Camion_Tipo, Peso_Bruto, Peso_Tara, Peso_Neto, Humedad, Retenciones, Impuresas)" 
                   "VALUES (:Folio_Num, :Chofer_Nombre, :Chofer_Apellidos, :Placas, :Camion_Color, :Camion_Tipo,"
                   ":Peso_Bruto, :Peso_Tara, :Peso_Neto, :Humedad, :Retenciones, :Impuresas)" );

    // valor.prepare( "INSERT INTO boletas (Chofer_Nombre) VALUES (:Chofer_Nombre)");              
    valor.bindValue(":Chofer_Nombre", nombre);
    valor.bindValue(":Chofer_Apellidos", apellidos); // unir las dos variables
    valor.bindValue(":Placas", predio);
    valor.exec();
    //QSqlQuery valor;
    //valor.exec("");

    if (!valor.exec()){
        QMessageBox::warning( this, "Error", "\n \n No se Pudo Guardar");
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information( this, "Nuevo Registro", "\n \n Se a creado un Nuevo Registro con exito");
    }

    mData.close();
}
```

Edit 1:

I edited like you people told me, and add more bindvalue() for every place holder, if i pass the info directly its recorded but not from a variable `valor.bindValue(":Retenciones", "retencio");`, sadly if I remove the database, it wont create the database again, and once the record it made, I'm unable to make any new record unless I restart the program, I have to use 2 `valor.exec()` in order to make it work

I'm back one step, any idea what am I messing up?

```
QSqlQuery valor;
valor.prepare("CREATE TABLE boletas "
           "(Folio_Num INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
           "Chofer_Nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Chofer_Apellidos VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
           "Placas VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
           "Camion_Color VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Camion_Tipo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
           "Peso_Bruto INTEGER NOT NULL, Peso_Tara INTEGER NOT NULL,"
           "Peso_Neto INTEGER NOT NULL, Humedad DOUBLE NOT NULL,"
           "Retenciones DOUBLE NOT NULL, Impuresas DOUBLE NOT NULL )");
valor.exec();
valor.prepare( "INSERT INTO boletas ( Chofer_Nombre, Chofer_Apellidos, Placas, Camion_Color,"
               "Camion_Tipo, Peso_Bruto, Peso_Tara, Peso_Neto, Humedad, Retenciones, Impuresas)" 
               "VALUES (:Chofer_Nombre, :Chofer_Apellidos, :Placas, :Camion_Color, :Camion_Tipo,"
               ":Peso_Bruto, :Peso_Tara, :Peso_Neto, :Humedad, :Retenciones, :Impuresas)" );  
valor.bindValue(":Chofer_Nombre", nombre);
valor.bindValue(":Chofer_Apellidos", apellidos); // unir las dos variables
valor.bindValue(":Placas", predio);
valor.bindValue(":Camion_Color", color);
valor.bindValue(":Camion_Tipo", tipo);
valor.bindValue(":Peso_Bruto", "bruto" );
valor.bindValue(":Peso_Tara", "tara");
valor.bindValue(":Peso_Neto", "neto");
valor.bindValue(":Humedad", humedad);
valor.bindValue(":Retenciones", "retencio");
valor.bindValue(":Impuresas", "impuresas");
valor.exec();
```

Ok I did erase everything and started from scratch, the problem was 2 things:

1. the QlineEdit its passing and empty string every time
2. there was an if who check if the tables were valid and was stopping the prepare function to create the query

I did manage to fix the sqlite side by simplify the code, just for safety I'm recording everything into a Text file, the qline edit still get me an empty string, will try to check it

Comment: You've created a prepared statement for the insert but only bound the values for three placeholders: `:Chofer_Nombre`, `:Chofer_Apellidos`, `:Placas`. You need to do the same for the other placeholders too: `:Camion_Color`, `:Camion_Tipo`, `:Peso_Bruto`, `:Peso_Tara`, `:Peso_Neto`, `:Humedad`, `:Retenciones`, `:Impuresas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try printing `valor.lastError().text()` to see what is the error text (to use this member, QSqlError should be included). You have two main problems in your command:

1. valor.exec() is executing two times. I recommend to delete this line and only keep the `if (!valor.exec()){` line.
2. You've mentioned 12 items in the prepare command, but only three of them are binded values.

**Edit1:**

You can make your code neat as follows and see that which line causes an error:

```
//obtener info del formulario boletas
    QString nombre= "nombre";
    QString apellido1= "apellido1";
    QString apellido2= "apellido2";
    QString predio= "predio";
    QString ubicacion= "ubicacion";
    QString chofer= "chofer";
    QString c_apellido1= "c_apellido1";
    QString c_apellido2= "c_apellido2";
    QString placas= "placas";
    QString color= "color";
    QString tipo= "tipo";
    QString apellidos = apellido1+" "+apellido2;


      QString name_db="CICLO-OI-19-20.db"; //  Base de Datos del Ciclo

      QSqlDatabase mData=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); // pones el tipo de driver de la db, en este caso QMYSQL
      mData.setDatabaseName(name_db);
      if (mData.open()) {

          // llena la base de datos usando QSqlQuery
          QSqlQuery valor;
          if (valor.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS boletas "
                         "(Folio_Num INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                         "Chofer_Nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Chofer_Apellidos VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                         "Placas VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                         "Camion_Color VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Camion_Tipo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                         "Peso_Bruto INTEGER NOT NULL, Peso_Tara INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                         "Peso_Neto INTEGER NOT NULL, Humedad DOUBLE NOT NULL,"
                         "Retenciones DOUBLE NOT NULL, Impuresas DOUBLE NOT NULL )")) {

              //---> Table created successfully ---> Now, insert data

              if (valor.prepare( "INSERT INTO boletas ( Chofer_Nombre, Chofer_Apellidos, Placas, Camion_Color,"
                                 "Camion_Tipo, Peso_Bruto, Peso_Tara, Peso_Neto, Humedad, Retenciones, Impuresas)"
                                 "VALUES (:Chofer_Nombre, :Chofer_Apellidos, :Placas, :Camion_Color, :Camion_Tipo,"
                                 ":Peso_Bruto, :Peso_Tara, :Peso_Neto, :Humedad, :Retenciones, :Impuresas)" )) {

                  //Query prepared successfully ---> Now, bind values
                  valor.bindValue(":Chofer_Nombre", nombre);
                  valor.bindValue(":Chofer_Apellidos", apellidos); // unir las dos variables
                  valor.bindValue(":Placas", predio);
                  valor.bindValue(":Camion_Color", color);
                  valor.bindValue(":Camion_Tipo", tipo);
                  valor.bindValue(":Peso_Bruto", "bruto" );
                  valor.bindValue(":Peso_Tara", "tara");
                  valor.bindValue(":Peso_Neto", "neto");
                  valor.bindValue(":Humedad", 12);
                  valor.bindValue(":Retenciones", "retencio");
                  valor.bindValue(":Impuresas", "impuresas");

                  if(valor.exec()){

                      qDebug() << "data inserted successfully!";
                  } else {

                      qDebug() << "Unable to execute query because: " << endl << valor.lastError().text();
                  }
              } else {

                  qDebug() << "Unable to prepare the query because: " << endl << valor.lastError().text();
              }
          } else {

              qDebug() << "Unable to create the table because: " << endl << valor.lastError().text();
          }

          mData.close();
      } else {

          qDebug() << "Unable to open database because: " << endl << mData.lastError().text();
      }
```

Comment: Please notice that data types must match with those you defined in the table creation command. For example, you've defined "Peso_Bruto" as INTEGER, but in the bindValue, you are passing a QString to it. Please resolve this problem in all your binding values and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: well, thats the odd thing, the column humedad its declared as integer double, but i can pass an string, because its directly declared, not passed as variable, as well retenciones, impuresas, etc. im having an odd behavior with this database

Comment: Although you can pass a string without any compile error, but if you print the last error (after binding values) by using ```valor.lastError().text()``` you will see that Qt returns a datatype mismatch error. Please see my Edit1.

Comment: after too many trys i had to write the `valor.lastError().text()` into a text file and the problem its: **No query Unable to fetch row**, basically the problem its on the sqlite side, i did try using `addBinderValue()` and the question mark place holder, not luck, i will check sql tutorials and try to figure it out what went wrong

Comment: Which line returns that error **No query Unable to fetch row***?

Comment: the last one, `valor.prepare( INSERT INTO... ` i will try a more direct approach without using binders, like `valor(INSERT INTO...` not the best option but im running out of ideas, just in case i would try my SQL code on DB Browser just in case im missing something, would check later

Comment: found the culprit, its the QLineEdit, it simply pass empty values not the actual values that have been writen by the user `QString nombre = wpp.Nombre_Productor_edit->text()` gives me an empty string, but if i use `QString nombre = " Productor"` it works perfectly, dont know if im passing the data wrong  `wpp.setupUi(this)` (declared as public, `Ui::Pantalla_Principal wpp;`) contains the actual QLineEdit that im using, it simply erase the text and pass an empty string